# Geth can't connected to via Websocket

Tags: go-ethereum, port-numbers, websocket

I am trying to connect to Geth via Websockets but unfortunately i am given 403 error.
I am using the `--ws --wsport XXXX args.`

Everything is done in a local instance, so that would be surprising if it has something to do with the port.

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code how you are trying to connect.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

At a guess, it's because of this:

`--ws.origins value Origins from which to accept websockets requests`

I encountered the same `403` error, added `--ws.origins="*"`, and was able to connect.  Please note that for security reasons you most likely do **NOT** want to allow `*` but instead be more explicit.

Comment: What is safe way to use `--wsorigins` instead of using `--wsorigins="*"` ? @Dan Turner

Comment: fyi this has changed to `--ws.origins`

Answer (score 7):

Below is an answer for errors when connecting from web3.js WebsocketProvider.

## Short Answer

If there is client's host noted inside `origin '<...>'` in message, just specify it with geth as `geth --ws --wsorigins <...>`.

If the host field is empty, specify the `Origin` header inside `WebsocketProvider`'s options like:

```
const wsProvider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://localhost:8546", {
  headers: {
    Origin: "some_meaningful_name"
  }
});
web3 = new Web3(wsProvider);
```

and run geth with `geth --ws --wsorigins some_meaningful_name`.

## Rationale

*Please note that the below rationale especially focuses on empty `origin ''`.*

1. Basically, `origin '<...>' not allowed on WS-RPC interface` is caused because geth [defaults to only accept connections from `http://localhost`, if not specified with `--wsorigins` option](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/rpc/websocket.go#L99). The error is also caused with empty `''` when websocket's `Origin` header is not specified while geth client requires it.
2. websocket's `Origin` is a header set by the browser. Why does such header exists in websocket protocol and why geth asks for it? This is to protect possible abuse and hijacking from other sites since WebSockets are not restrained by the same-origin policy(see [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115716/is-the-origin-header-really-useful-for-securing-a-websocket) and [this](https://www.christian-schneider.net/CrossSiteWebSocketHijacking.html)). But also, note that `Origin` header is subject to be manipulated since it's only a header added by the browser.
3. The [`WebsocketProvider` that web3 1.0 provides now](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/1.0/packages/web3-providers-ws) is a websocket for the node(dependent on [WebSocket-Node](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node)). You can use it on the browser side too, but note that in a browser environment even if you manually pass `Origin` header onto the provider(see final code section), browser will automatically override that value with the current host. So when connecting from a browser using websocket, what you need to make sure is that the expected host is added correctly onto geth's `--wsorigins`.
4. On the other hand, when a websocket is used in node, `Origin` header may not have a valid meaning, since the websocket connection from a node process is not really in a user-agent scenario where the script is provided by the domain. From [the WebSocket-Node documentation](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/blob/master/docs/WebSocketClient.md#connectrequesturl-requestedprotocols-origin-headers-requestoptions):

> `origin` is an optional field that can be used in user-agent scenarios to identify the page containing any scripting content that caused the connection to be requested. (**This seems unlikely in node.. probably should leave it null most of the time.**)

This is why the [web3 code](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/1.0/packages/web3-providers-ws/src/index.js#L78) left it `undefined` by default. But still, **you can set the `Origin` header with the `options` object**(which is the 2nd param of `WebsocketProvider` constructor) with `headers` > `Origin` key, [which will](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/1.0/packages/web3-providers-ws/src/index.js#L72) [eventually](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/blob/master/lib/WebSocketClient.js#L178) [written into the `Origin` header](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/blob/master/lib/WebSocketClient.js#L190).

To sum up, one can just go with `--wsorigins *` option for geth if security is not of much concern, or rather specify `origin` header explicitly with some meaningful string(or the actual host) on the web3 websocket provider and pass the value onto geth's `--wsorigins`. One easy option is to set the `Origin` header as `http://localhost` on web3 ws-provider, and run geth without `--wsorigins` since geth defaults to accept connections from `http://localhost`.

[*Adapted from my own comment on a similar issue*](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16608#issuecomment-386872941)

Comment: Overall is it secure to use `geth` with following web socket flags as follows: `--ws --wsaddr="127.0.0.1" --wsorigins "*"` ?

Comment: @alper It depends on your context of usage. Check out https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16608#issuecomment-386872941

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify origins which allowed to connect to WebSocket server of Geth:

```
geth --ws --ws.origins "<origin 1>,<origin 2>,<origin n>"
```