# What is the safest way to use WS-RPC server in geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, websocket

In this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11619/4575), it is suggested that it is not safe to use `--wsorigins="*"` for security reasons. What are the security reasons?

**=>** How could I make `WS-RPC server` connection secure in `geth`?

If I use following flags, would it be enough for security: `--ws --wsaddr="127.0.0.1" --wsorigins "*"`; where I have replace `-wsaddr="0.0.0.0"` with `-wsaddr="127.0.0.1"` in order to connect only from `localhost`.

---

> --wsaddr value         WS-RPC server listening interface
>
> --ws                   Enable the WS-RPC server
>
> --wsorigins value      Origins from which to accept websockets requests

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb, any open port is a security risk. The best way to prevent an attack by malicious actor would be to have no doors and no windows.

Specifically, in blockchain nodes, the risk is stealing funds from the account the node operates, or just overloading your node with requests.

So by default, the node listens only to `localhost` loopback interface, so you'll be able to connect locally using either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` IP from the server itself.

If you wish to connect from another device on the same LAN, you can bind the node to its LAN IP address, such as `192.168.1.6`, it will then listen only on this local IP and shouldn't be listening to your public internet IP.

By using `--wsorigins="*"` you connections from any interface to be accepted, even ones coming from the internet, which unless you have a router blocking these - is risky.

If you have a well configured firewall and filter ports properly, your machine should be safe from external internet access and can safely use `--wsorigins="*"`, but again - that's only if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to whitelist your dApp IP/domain

Example:

```
geth --http --http.corsdomain <YOUR IP or DOMAIN>
```

All information you can find [here](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/server)