# GETH Proper Way of Setting --ws.origins

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

My application and GETH sits on the same server.  I only want GETH to accept WS connection on the same server.  What is the proper way of setting --ws.origins ?  Historically I just used --ws.origins * but I'm sure that is not good practice.

I'm thinking --ws.origins "127.0.0.1" or --ws.origins "ws://127.0.0.1"

Comment: Is there a particular reason not to use IPC in this case?

Comment: That's a good question.  I've always used WSS.  Apologies my technical expertise on this is... not the greatest.  Can I use IPC with web3.js ?

Comment: I'm also assuming IPC might give a performance boost ?

Comment: You can. IPC is generally the way to go if the application sits on the same machine as geth. It's faster, and security is much improved. Check out 'web3.js IPCProvider'.

Comment: Thanks man.  You might actually have solved two problems for me here

Comment: @SimonR do you have any experience with web3-eth-admin?  IPC works fine for normal web3 but throws crazy errors for the admin class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Geth can't connected to via Websocket](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11527/geth-cant-connected-to-via-websocket)